# Matlab Mex Compile Error

Tags: matlab, mex

I'm trying to run other's MATLAB program for testing.

They use Mex to compile some C code.
I got an error information from the following code:

```
mex -O fconvblas.cc -lmwblas -o fconv
```

The error information is:

C:\PROGRA~1\MATLAB\R2013A\BIN\MEX.PL: Error: Unrecognized switch: -o.

Is there anyone can tell me what's wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the `-o` switch with `-output`.

This specifies the output binary MEX-file name.